# Delete redundant SQL Server rows

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server tables: Date and Tracking.
In the first table (Date) we have only 2 columns

```
(fields):
Date_ID (int primary key) 
Date_Date (datetime).
```

In the second one (Tracking), we have 4 columns:

```
-Tracking_ID (int primary key)
-Date_ID (int foreign key)
-Place_ID (int foreign key)
-Label_ID (int foreign key).
```

The primary key for Tracking is the triplet (Date_ID,Place_ID,Label_ID)

I want to delete, from Tracking table, rows that have the same date_date but with a different date_id, and the same Place_ID and Label_ID
Iwant to keep just the row that has the smallest Date_ID.

For example we have the following 2 rows in the table Tracking:

```
row1: Tracking_ID=1;Date_ID=109;Place_ID=55;Label_ID=40
row2: Tracking_ID=2;Date_ID=110;Place_ID=55;Label_ID=40
```

and we have the following 2 rows in the table Date:

```
row1: Date_ID=109; Date_Date=2014-05-28 00:00:00
row2: Date_ID=110; Date_Date=2014-05-28 00:00:00
```

My purpose is to delete row 2 from Tracking since it is the row having the smallest date_id for the same triplet (date_date,Place_ID,Label_ID).

Can anyone has the most optimised solution?

Thanks

Comment: just to note: `from Tracking since it is the row having the smallest date_id` you maybe mean biggest Date_ID

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the row having the smallest Date_ID so I delete the row having the biggest one :D

Comment: @user3569267, I feel like your comment is wrong. If you have 3 records, then identifying the largest wont help. I think we should find the minimum value and join based on it.

Comment: Can we did it without cursor? IF yes, can you tell me how (in SQL syntaxe) if you please..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example.

First I collect bad `Tracking_IDs`
And then I delete them.

```
DECLARE @Date TABLE(
    Date_ID int,
    Date_Date datetime
)

DECLARE @Tracking TABLE(
    Tracking_ID int,
    Date_ID int,
    Place_ID int,
    Label_ID int
)

DECLARE @ForDelete TABLE(
    Tracking_ID int
)

INSERT INTO @Date SELECT 109,'2014-05-28 00:00:00'
INSERT INTO @Date SELECT 110,'2014-05-28 00:00:00'
INSERT INTO @Date SELECT 111,'2014-05-29 00:00:00'
INSERT INTO @Date SELECT 112,'2014-05-29 00:00:00'
INSERT INTO @Date SELECT 113,'2014-05-29 00:00:00'

INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 1, 109, 55, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 2, 110, 55, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 3, 110, 56, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 4, 111, 55, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 5, 111, 55, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 6, 112, 57, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 7, 111, 57, 40
INSERT INTO @Tracking SELECT 8, 113, 57, 40

;WITH test AS (
SELECT T.Tracking_ID, T.Date_ID, T.Place_ID, T.Label_ID, D.Date_Date
FROM @Tracking AS T
INNER JOIN @Date AS D
    ON T.Date_ID = D.Date_ID
)
INSERT INTO @ForDelete
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Tracking_ID
FROM test as t1
INNER JOIN test as t2
    ON t1.Date_Date = t2.Date_Date
    AND t1.Place_ID = t2.Place_ID
    AND t1.Label_ID = t2.Label_ID
    AND t1.Date_ID > t2.Date_ID

DELETE FROM T
FROM @Tracking AS T
INNER JOIN @ForDelete AS FD
    ON FD.Tracking_ID = T.Tracking_ID

SELECT *
FROM @Tracking
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way would be to delete straight from the cte rather than putting it into a temporary deleting table:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT D.Date_Date, T.Date_ID, T.Place_ID, T.Label_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Place_ID, T.Label_ID ORDER BY T.Date_ID) AS RowNum
FROM  [Date] D
INNER JOIN Tracking T ON D.Date_ID = T.Date_ID)

DELETE T
FROM cte
INNER JOIN Tracking T ON cte.Date_ID = T.Date_ID AND cte.Place_ID = T.Place_ID AND cte.Label_ID = T.Label_ID
WHERE RowNum > 1
```